# Nesting Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do something which, in theory, should be simple.  I've Googled for the answer, but haven't come across anything yet that has worked.  I'm using Angular JS 1.4.9.  What I want to happen is to have this:

```
<site-menu>
   <site-menu-item title="Search" href="#/search"/>
   <site-menu-item title="Reports" href="#/reports"/>
   <site-menu-item title="About" href="#/about"/>
</site-menu>
```

turn in to this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#/search">Search</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/reports">Reports</a></li>
   <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to do this as a directive so that when the user clicks one the links, I can apply an "active" CSS style to the LI element.  For the life of me, though, I can't get it to work.  To be honest, transclusion and compiling (if either of these are what it takes) has always been my weak point with Angular 1.x.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using ui-router by chance?, Because it has ui-sref-active directive that handle this out of the box.

Comment: Are you getting any errors, what is appearing?

Comment: Nicolas, no, I'm not using ui-router.  This is actually a pretty simple application, so I haven't brought anything in yet outside of Angular itself.  However, I'll check it out.  I've not actually used the ui-router module yet, as I've not yet needed anything fancy in the apps I've worked on so far beyond what the standard router gets me.  I'll play around with it, and get back to you.

Comment: Malkus, no, no errors.  In what I've tried so far, it just doesn't render anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need of using transclusion or compiling, i made a little directive to manage this so we have something to play with. Next time it would be better if you provide with more details or code example.

Try something like this and let me know:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('siteMenu', [function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          menus: '='
        },
        controller: SiteMenuController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'site-menu-template.html'
      };

      function SiteMenuController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.selected = 0;

        vm.onClick= function(index) {
          vm.selected = index; 
        };
      }
  }])

  .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('site-menu-template.html',
      '<ul>' +
        '<li ng-repeat="menu in vm.menus" ng-click="onClick($index)" ng-class="{active: $index == vm.selected}">' +
          '<a ng-href="#/{{ menu }}">{{ menu }}</a>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>'
    );
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Directive usage:

```
<site-menu menus="['search', 'reports', 'about']"></site-menu>
```

Comment: You're right, of course.  My bad, I should know better.  :)  I will definitely save this code snippet for later use, but I've ultimately used UI Router as you'd recommended in your previous post.  I'd not used that library before, though I've heard of it, and if worked splendidly, so thanks!!!  I'm not sure why I can't mark your original answer as the one I ran with, but I'll mark this one so you get credit.

Comment: @JamieNordmeyer you can't mark a comment as a correct answer. But if you consider this answer helpful please upvote the answer instead of the comment. Thanks!

Comment: Done.  I've answered more questions on here then I've asked, so I'm honestly a bit flaky on this side of things, but will know better next time around.  :)  Regardless, I definitely appreciate the help.